# Swing JFrame content save to html file

Tags: java, html, swing

Used `JFrame` and split pane to display the difference between a two large content. It shows the difference and coloring the difference. So It looks like a table with colored difference. Is it possible to save it as HTML file?

`JEditorPane` and `HTMLEditorKit` are using only text content to save it in a file.  do I need to manually do the difference and color it again in the HTML?

Is there a way to copy the table content from Swing to HTML?

private void saveToHTML(File selectedFile){

```
     ConfigurationDiffUtil util = new ConfigurationDiffUtil(previous.getRuRO().getContent(), latest.getRuRO().getContent());

     JEditorPane yourEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
     yourEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");
     yourEditorPane.setText(util.getLeftEditor().getText());



    if (selectedFile.isDirectory()) {  

        String deviceFolderName = selectedFile.getPath() + File.separator + escapeFileName(deviceId.getName()); 
         File deviceFolder = new File(deviceFolderName);
         if ( (deviceFolder.exists() && confirmOverwrite(deviceFolderName)) || deviceFolder.mkdir()) {

                String saveFileName = escapeFileName(deviceId.getName())+"."+ "html";
                File dataFile  = new File (deviceFolder, saveFileName);
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataFile));


        HTMLWriter hw = new HTMLWriter(out, (HTMLDocument) yourEditorPane.getDocument());
        hw.write();


        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.error(this, "ExportCredentials:credentials file not found",e);

    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        Log.error(this, "ExportCredentials:credentials file not found",e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.error(this, "ExportCredentials:unable to read the file",e);

    }       
         }
    }

}
```

Now I have created this code snippet. Here I am setting the left pane content.
yourEditorPane.setText(util.getLeftEditor().getText());

It is saving it in a html file.

Here I could save only text in the html. The look and feel from swing (left and right contents in a table and show the highlight difference), not able to get it in HTML. Only Text can be saved into HTML?

Comment: *"It shows the difference and coloring the difference."*  How?  Note that the color (for the differences) might be rendered as HTML.  `JEditorPane` & `JTextPane` support (simple) HTML rendering.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have the java code to compute the difference and paint the color. So JFrame contains the splitpane with the colored difference. Now I wanted to save it to a html file exactly the same content.

Comment: *"I have the java code.."*  ..M-C-V-E.  Note that after *reading* your comment, I am still not clear on whether the changes are rendered in HTML using an HTML aware component, or rendered direct to a `BufferedImage`, or..  But don't try and describe it in words.  **Let the MCVE do the talking.**

Comment: No. I could not render it in the HTML.

Comment: I an render it in HTML. But I am still waiting to see that MCVE..

Comment: The code was already developed to display the content in SWING.
 i) Getting the difference report between two arrays (used Diff class which uses the hashtable to get the difference)
ii) By passing the difference report, compare the original with the difference using the classes org.syntax.jedit.JEditTextArea and org.syntax.jedit.TextAreaPainter and paint the difference. 
iii) This value is populated to the splitpane. 
iv) I have created a button to save to HTML File. 
On click of the save to HTML, I have to render this split pane content in HTML Format.

Comment: I am stuck with saving the html file as it is displayed by the swing component including the look and feel.

Comment: How many times do I have to say this before it sinks in?  I'll try a little louder this time.  ***For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).***  I have voted to close, based on 'lack of an MCVE'.

Comment: My question is: Is it possible to get the same look and feel (Show the contents in two split pane and highlight the difference) from SWING to HTML? or I need to create manually a table with the two contents as different column and highlight the difference?

Comment: I do not have any code currently on click of the SAVE TO HTML Button. I am finding the different ways to render the content and look and feel to the html from the SWING.

Comment: I voted to close the question as too broad. If you can provide a code or ask really specific question just update the question posting your code (MCVE is preferred)

Comment: But that is still not an MCVE!  Please, if there is something you don't understand about an MCVE, ask me - I am well placed to explain, but be specific about what you don't understand..

Answer (score 0):

In Swing Application:

```
JPanel editorPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JideSplitPane splitPane = new JideSplitPane();
splitPane.add(diffUtil.getLeftEditor()));
splitPane.add(diffUtil.getRightEditor()));
editorPanel.add(splitPane);
```

In Swing, I got the dialog window populating two contents in left and right pane and the difference is colored.

In this Panel I have a button to saveToHTML. On click of the button I have to store the content displayed in this popup to the HTML.

SaveToHTML Button onclick, I have written this function.

```
ConfigurationDiffUtil util = new ConfigurationDiffUtil(previous.getRuRO().getContent(),     latest.getRuRO().getContent());

 JEditorPane yourEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
 yourEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");
// yourEditorPane.setText(util.getLeftEditor().getText());
JideSplitPane splitPane = new JideSplitPane();

        splitPane.add(diffUtil.getLeftEditor()));
splitPane.add(diffUtil.getRightEditor()));

        yourEditorPane.add(splitPane);


 if (selectedFile.isDirectory()) {  

    String deviceFolderName = selectedFile.getPath() + File.separator + escapeFileName(deviceId.getName()); 
     File deviceFolder = new File(deviceFolderName);
     if ( (deviceFolder.exists() && confirmOverwrite(deviceFolderName)) || deviceFolder.mkdir()) {

            String saveFileName = escapeFileName(deviceId.getName())+"."+ "html";
            File dataFile  = new File (deviceFolder, saveFileName);
 try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataFile));


    HTMLWriter hw = new HTMLWriter(out, (HTMLDocument) yourEditorPane.getDocument());
    hw.write();


    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.error(this, "ExportCredentials:credentials file not found",e);

} catch (BadLocationException e) {
    Log.error(this, "ExportCredentials:credentials file not found",e);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.error(this, "ExportCredentials:unable to read the file",e);

}       
     }
}
```

}[image: Panel from Swing showing difference]

i)   setText shows the content in the html page.

```
 yourEditorPane.setText(util.getLeftEditor().getText());
```

this line shows me the text content in the html.

ii) I tried to add this split pane to the JEditorPane.

```
JideSplitPane splitPane = new JideSplitPane();

        splitPane.add(diffUtil.getLeftEditor()));
splitPane.add(diffUtil.getRightEditor()));

        yourEditorPane.add(splitPane);
```

But nothing is displayed in the html page. 
I need to display the same content from the splitPane to the HTML page.

Thank you.